# totals in a loop do not add up

Tags: java, loops

So I decided to skirt around the card generator, thanks to another poster on a previous question. I have had a lot of good ideas from the community and I'm trying not to copy paste, and keep the work as genuine as possible.

Which is why some problems aren't fixed yet, and others have popped up.

That said, when I run this version, the totals don't add up properly, I think on the second hit it goes a bit haywire. So I would love a little more encouragement :)

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class blackj
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;

    boolean playing = true;
    boolean notPlaying = true;
    int card1 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
    int card2 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
    int dcard1 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
    int dcard2 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);

    int ptotal = card1 +card2;
    int dtotal = dcard1 +dcard2;

    {   


        System.out.println("Welcome to Blackjack ! " );
            System.out.println("Score as close to 21 without going over to win ");
                System.out.println("What is your name?");
            name = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Hello " + name);
                System.out.println("Let's play some BlackJack!");
            System.out.println("The dealer shows: \n\t\t" +dcard1 );
            System.out.println("Your first card is: \n\t\t " +card1 );
            System.out.println("Your second card is: \n\t\t" +card2  );
            System.out.println("Giving you a grand total of: " +ptotal );

        while (playing)
            {
            System.out.println("Would you like to (H)it or (S)tick?");
                Scanner hit1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                String a = hit1.nextLine();
                if(a.equals("h"))
            {
                int newCard = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
                System.out.println("Your next card is " +newCard );
                int pcurrent = ptotal +newCard;
                System.out.println("Giving you a new total of "+pcurrent);
                    if ((pcurrent >=22))
                    {
                System.out.println("You Busted! \nSorry! you lose");
                playing = false;
                    }
                playing = true;
                    if(a.equals("s"))
            {
                System.out.println("You stick at " +pcurrent );
                System.out.println("Now it's the dealers turn\n Dealer must draw until 17");
            }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Please press H or S");
            }

            }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger and stepping through the code to see where it's behaviour deviates from your expectation?

Comment: I am encouraged in college not to use any debugger software, I should be able to see the logic without it. obviously I can't lol. but I will do it as a last resort. hopefully it won't be necessary.

Comment: I think that this restriction does NOT make sense ;)

Comment: I agree, since I'm a total newb, and java is far from logical in my eyes :)

Comment: I understand what they are suggesting, but using the logic behind that I suspect that asking someone to point out errors in your code comes even lower in what they would prefer that you do

Comment: well ... I guess, but without a reference of what is logical and what is not, I might as well play golf in the evenings. Because me and google keep coming up short on how to fix the problem in the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code a bit and now it works.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Blackjack
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        String name;
        Scanner scannerIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean playing = true;
        int card1 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
        int card2 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
        int dcard1 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
        int dcard2 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);

        int ptotal = card1 +card2;
        int dtotal = dcard1 +dcard2;

        System.out.println("Welcome to Blackjack ! " );
        System.out.println("Score as close to 21 without going over to win ");
        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        name = scannerIn.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hello " + name);
        System.out.println("Let's play some BlackJack!");
        System.out.println("The dealer shows: \n\t\t" +dcard1 );
        System.out.println("Your first card is: \n\t\t " +card1 );
        System.out.println("Your second card is: \n\t\t" +card2  );
        System.out.println("Giving you a grand total of: " +ptotal );


        while (playing)
        {
            System.out.println("Would you like to (H)it or (S)tick?");
            String a = scannerIn.nextLine();
            if(a.toLowerCase().equals("h"))
            {
                int newCard = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
                System.out.println("Your next card is " +newCard );
                ptotal = ptotal +newCard;
                System.out.println("Giving you a new total of "+ptotal);
                if ((ptotal >=22))
                {
                    System.out.println("You Busted! \nSorry! you lose");
                    playing = false;
                }

            }else if(a.toLowerCase().equals("s"))
            {
                System.out.println("You stick at " +ptotal );
                System.out.println("Now it's the dealers turn\n Dealer must draw until 17");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Please press H or S");
            }

        }
        scannerIn.close();
    }
}
```

I made the following changes:

- Using only one variable for ptotal, which sums up.
- Removing one block { ... }, which had no meaning
- Capitalize the class name. (Because it's a java convetion)
- Ensure that only one scanner is opened and closed within your program.
- Moving the if which checks for the '*s*' letter, so that it is reachable.
- Modifiying your if-else structure to avoid unnecessary checks
- Removing the unused variable notPlaying
- Ensuring that both capitalized and lower-case inputs are accepted.

Comment: Wow Great! Thanks a lot. I had problems with variables already existing, and didn't thing the String a=ScannerIn.nextLine(); would work like that. So I learned a new thing today. :) Moving the checks for the letter "s" so that its reachable?? can you explain that to me? The notplaying variable will come into use when the dealers turn comes. But yeah for right now it's not usful. The upper and lower case inputs worked fine I think with the .equals command. but maybe I'm wrong on that.
Thanks for the help on this :)

Comment: I have some questions about your edits, if you have the time, posted above this message.

Comment: You had the if statement which checks if s was typed with in a part fo your code that ensured an h was typed. Just but the code for the dealer after the computation of the input. So it will be computed before the reading of a new input. You should not use an other variable.

Comment: Actually, the problem is still there, if I need to hit more than once, the sum of the 4 cards is incorrect. it still adds the card1+card2 +newCard only, so if i draw 3+4+(6)+4 my new total will be 11 rather than 17.

Comment: For me it works, so you seem to have changed something. Why do you add (6) in brackets?

Comment: If I use placeholder int variables the loop will not recognize them, my first effort had Ptotal = card1+card2, ptotal2=ptotal1+card3 etc. but then I had more than 30 int's in play and it looks very messy.

Comment: (6) is the first newCard, which doesn't get added to the new total when the next (4) is drawn.

If you play a few games and hit more than 3 times, you'll see the math isn't quite right, maybe I did change something... I'll copy paste again and see if it works for me.

Comment: I do not see why you need ptotal1, ptotal2 and so on. And why you'd need the total of every round rather than a global total for each player. I tested my code and it works, and I am a bit disappointed that you are removing the reputation from my correct answer, after having taken time to help you.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2nkrlw2/8  if you see the console, the hit function math is not working, follow the game I start with 11, hit for 7, which gives me 18. I hit again for 11, which gives me a total of 22. 
Each new card isn't being added to the new total.

Comment: That's weird. Are your sure, that your output belongs to the current program version? Ensure you recompile. Better use Eclipse. The output makes sense with your old code but not with mine!!!

Comment: I am limited to Java7 because that's what my college uses, I am not allowed to use other software other than notepad++ and the console. Sucks to be me....

Comment: I had a thought... brace yourself! could I use a second loop while (counting) and store the ptotal inside it. then +newCard for each turn of the loop?

Comment: you must at least compile the code I gave you and follow some advice, like using eclipse or a debugger to help yourself. Eclipse works together java7 and it helps a lot. You can copy your code back to notepad. Maybe it will atleast prevent you from not compiling your code propperly!

Comment: I did compile the code in the console, and it just doesn't work for me, and it won't work in my college where it will be tested because they aren't using Eclipse either. I know your code works in Eclipse, you told me so, and I believe you. The college won't accept that as an excuse for malfunctioning programs. I will keep trying, and hopefully I can find a work around, and I will compile the code in Eclipse and copy it back to notepad and see if it makes a difference. Thanks for all your efforts I am very grateful for everything you've done.

Comment: It does not matter in which program the code that works is written. Valid code is valid code. Maybe you must delete your .class files in your environment before compiling!

Comment: Ok so I'm an idiot... who knew? Your code works perfectly, I had file name vs class name issue, which compiled the wrong code, the errors I was seeing were from my own broken code and not yours. After I deleted the old file and made a new save with the correct class name everything ran smoothly. I just wanted to let you know, and thank you again. I'll mark this as the correct answer, and thumbs up if I'm allowed.

Comment: Thanks. As I told you. If you like to pass your class I highly recommend you to follow the other advices which were given to you also! Furthermore a book about Java might also help!

Comment: Yeah, I do need a better book!, I got Java-in-easy-steps, which doesn't begin to cover the groundwork needed for a project like this. The funny thing is, it's not actually very hard once you see it done. But the book doesn't go further than the very simple. which is what is making me flail about so much during coding. Thanks again.

Comment: You only need to understand what each element semantically does and learn the syntax and than you must understand how everything works your own in your head! 

In your exam you might have to write code on a blank paper. So working in an editor is good to learn the syntax. But Eclipse will help you finding mistakes in your code quicker and helps you with a debugger to debug your code. So I do recommend it also for beginners.